# Swift Updating variable inside of data task

Tags: swift, asynchronous, networking

I am writing a Network class for my app. One function carries out the actual request to the API I am using

as part of this function I am using a `URLSession.shard.dataTask()`.

```
var decodedResponse = SongLinkAPIResponse()
        
let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            
            let result = data.map(Result.success) ?? Result.failure(DataLoaderError.network(error!))
            let handlerResult = handler(result)
//          This handler just decodes the downloaded JSON into a SongLinkAPIResponse struct. 
//          This works fine and I can see this is working
            


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch handlerResult {
                    case .success(let response):
//                      When I run this code in a playground I can see that this line shows as working in the sidebar

                        decodedResponse = response
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        
task.resume()

//However when returning this variable it just has the empty default configuration of the struct

return decodedResponse
```

Any ideas on why the variable is not updating?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Answer (score 1):

`session.dataTask` is asynchronous. It will execute some time in the future.

Your code will execute in the following order.

```
// 1
var decodedResponse = SongLinkAPIResponse()

// 2        
let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            // 4
            ...
        }
        
task.resume()

// 3
return decodedResponse
```

Here are some possible explanations/solutions:

- [Function that returns asynchronously retrieved value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31794542/8697793)
- [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25203556/8697793)
- [Swift write an async/await method with return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57935483/8697793)

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense as to the order. Is there anyway that I can return the result of step 4?

Comment: @HarryDay I added some links - you may find more information there.